# Which of the two algorithms for finding out the suffix array is faster and why?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, suffix-array

I am new to algorithm complexity and therefore can't figure out the complexities of the following two algorithms. Both find out the suffix array for a given string. The first one is created by me by myself and the second one I found on the internet. I want to know which of them is faster and why?

FIRST ALGORITHM

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct suffix{
    string str;
    int pos;
};
int main()
{
    string input;
    suffix arr[100];
    getline(cin,input,'\n');
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<input.length();j++)
        {
            arr[i].str+=input[j];
        }
            arr[i].pos=i;

        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i].str.compare(arr[j].str)<0)    
            {
                string temp=arr[i].str;
                arr[i].str=arr[j].str;
                arr[j].str=temp;
                int tem=arr[i].pos;
                arr[i].pos=arr[j].pos;
                arr[j].pos=tem;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
        cout<<arr[i].pos<<",";
    return 0;
}
```

SECOND ALGORITHM

```
#include bits/stdc++.h  
using namespace std;

// suffixRank is table hold the rank of each string on each iteration  
// suffixRank[i][j] denotes rank of jth suffix at ith iteration  

int suffixRank[20][int(1E6)];

// Example "abaab"  
// Suffix Array for this (2, 3, 0, 4, 1)  
// Create a tuple to store rank for each suffix  

struct myTuple {  
    int originalIndex;   // stores original index of suffix  
    int firstHalf;       // store rank for first half of suffix  
    int secondHalf;      // store rank for second half of suffix  
};


// function to compare two suffix in O(1)  
// first it checks whether first half chars of 'a' are equal to first half chars of b  
// if they compare second half  
// else compare decide on rank of first half  

int cmp(myTuple a, myTuple b) {  
    if(a.firstHalf == b.firstHalf) return a.secondHalf < b.secondHalf;  
    else return a.firstHalf < b.firstHalf;  
}

int main() {

    // Take input string
    // initialize size of string as N

    string s; cin >> s;
    int N = s.size();

    // Initialize suffix ranking on the basis of only single character
    // for single character ranks will be 'a' = 0, 'b' = 1, 'c' = 2 ... 'z' = 25

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        suffixRank[0][i] = s[i] - 'a';

    // Create a tuple array for each suffix

    myTuple L[N];

    // Iterate log(n) times i.e. till when all the suffixes are sorted
    // 'stp' keeps the track of number of iteration
    // 'cnt' store length of suffix which is going to be compared

    // On each iteration we initialize tuple for each suffix array
    // with values computed from previous iteration

    for(int cnt = 1, stp = 1; cnt < N; cnt *= 2, ++stp) {

        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            L[i].firstHalf = suffixRank[stp - 1][i];
            L[i].secondHalf = i + cnt < N ? suffixRank[stp - 1][i + cnt] : -1;
            L[i].originalIndex = i;
        }

        // On the basis of tuples obtained sort the tuple array

        sort(L, L + N, cmp);

        // Initialize rank for rank 0 suffix after sorting to its original index
        // in suffixRank array

        suffixRank[stp][L[0].originalIndex] = 0;

        for(int i = 1, currRank = 0; i < N; ++i) {

            // compare ith ranked suffix ( after sorting ) to (i - 1)th ranked suffix
            // if they are equal till now assign same rank to ith as that of (i - 1)th
            // else rank for ith will be currRank ( i.e. rank of (i - 1)th ) plus 1, i.e ( currRank + 1 )

            if(L[i - 1].firstHalf != L[i].firstHalf || L[i - 1].secondHalf != L[i].secondHalf)
                ++currRank;

            suffixRank[stp][L[i].originalIndex] = currRank;
        }

    }

    // Print suffix array

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) cout << L[i].originalIndex << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run them both and see?

Comment: Both are printing the same answer. How to figure out which of them is faster?

Comment: You run both of them with a large enough input and measure how long they take to complete. The one that takes less time is the faster one.

Comment: Time them?  the is the [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library you can use to time your code.  You could also run  a profiler like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: @NathanOliver Valgrind can profile? I did not know that.

Comment: @BaummitAugen the first paragraph on the home page has `and profile your programs in detail.`.  I could be mistaken on what type of profiling it can do and it is not performance profiling.

Comment: @NathanOliver found out using std::chrono that second one is faster. Thank You. It was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To determine which one runs faster for a given `N`, you will need to run them both and see. In order to determine which one will scale better, though, you can simply look through your loops.

In your first algorithm, you have nested loops that both go from `0` to `input.size()` with increments of 1, which is `O(N^2)` (if `input.size()` is 1, both loops run once for a total of one run, if `input.size()` is 2, the outer loop runs twice, and the inner loop runs twice for each outer loop run for a total of 4 iterations, and so on).

The second algorithm, though, has an outer loop that goes from `0` to `N` and multiplies by `2` at each iteration. This grows as `log(N)` rather than `N`. As such, it is `O(N*log(N))`, which is less than `O(N^2)`, and is likely to scale better.